# Kubernetes oc rsync does not work due server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, rsync

I'm trying to copy folders between remote pod and my local but the rsync command always return the same error: *server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client*

I'm using oc without troubles behind a proxy (login, get, export...) but the troubles arise using rsync and rsh (interactive shell)

Using the logs of rsync process (--loglevel=10) I got the curl requests that is failling. Running this command via my terminal I got this error

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ***** (*.*.*.*) port * (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /**/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I have no idea how to solve that trouble, taking into account that for other people from the same place the process works so fine

---

Edit

The problem is behind the ssl certificates used. I found another curl call that fails due similar issue but for the others (behind the same proxy) works.

After remove completely my current installation (format disk and install a new Ubuntu 18.04 version) it is still not working. Then Anaconda is not the problem

<strike>I have Anaconda (conda server) installed and I think he problem is about the certificate. I uninstalled Anaconda and the error persist but with different values and throw a "Bad request error". Have, someone, troubles using "oc rsync (oc rsh ...)" with anaconda installed?</strike>

---

Edited

Finally is a proxy trouble. I did it from home, removing all proxy settings, connect via VPN and worked. The key issue is I do not where the setting is missing.

Proxy configured:
/etc/environment
~/.curlrc with proxy created and removed (for both was not working)

Comment: Deleted my answer since I realised this is likely a proxy related issue that you have hit. Can you ask a someone with with a working setup to run `env | grep RSYNC_PROXY` and see if this env var is set

Comment: Thanks Philip, the RSYNC_PROXY is not set (nor for me and my team mates). I think the problem is about certificates

Comment: Right. But the `oc rsync` command works for them on the same cluster and behind the same proxy? I was wondering was the proxy not configured or supporting rsync port, 873 by default I believe

Comment: Yes, It works for them behind the same proxy without RSYNC_PROXY configured as my case.